# Pentaho Spoon Does not launch

Tags: java, pentaho, spoon

I tried to open pentaho spoon but it doesnt launch . The error is "System does not find the path"
I use "-Xms1024m" and C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261 path as an environment but still does not working. Can someone help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper java location in set-pentaho-env file like

Write below 2 line in end of the file "set-pentaho-env.bat".

```
set _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261
set _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin\%__LAUNCHER%
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem . I needed to language options. 
if "%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS%"=="" set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m" "-Xmx1024m" "-Duser.country=US" "-Duser.language=en" 
"-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
this worked

Answer (score 0):

I have spent a couple of hours trying different options suggested in different website and found that defining _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME and _PENTAHO_JAVA in set-pentaho-env.bat is a very good idea so that you will have a good control over the java version if you install somewhere else other that Program Files. Additionally, I had to comment out in spoon.bat the following whatever is being used.

```
REM if "%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS%"=="" set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m" "-Xmx1024m" "-Duser.country=US" "-Duser.language=en" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

REM if "%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS%"=="" set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m" "-Xmx2048m"
```

Also, I have used only TLSv1.2 considering security concern.

Both the followings in set-pentaho-env.bat

```
set _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_301
set _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_301\bin\%__LAUNCHER%

set _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=F:\Java\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.222.10-hotspot\jre
set _PENTAHO_JAVA=F:\Java\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.222.10-hotspot\jre\bin\%__LAUNCHER%
```

Finally I used last two line as I want control the java version to avoid the change in the version pushed.